# Existence of $\xi$ s.t. $f'''\left(\xi\right)=\frac{3f''\left(\xi\right)}{1-\xi}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

> Given $f(x)\in C^3$, and $f(0)=f(1/2)=f(1)$. Prove that there exists *at least* one point $\xi$, such that $f'''\left(\xi\right)=\dfrac{3f''\left(\xi\right)}{1-\xi}$.

I tried to apply [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) to $f(x)$, but anyway I can't construct the denominator $1-\xi$. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by **Rolles theorem** there exist some $c_1,c_2$ such that $f'(c_1)=f'(c_2)=0$  where $c_1\in(0,1/2),c_2\in(1/2,1)$again by Rolle's there is some $c_3$ such that $f''(c_3)=0$, $c_3\in(c_1,c_2)$.

Now consider $$h(x)={(1-x)}^3 f''(x)$$ $$h(1)=h(c_3)=0$$ Then by Rolle's theorem there is some $\eta$: $$h'(\eta)=0\Rightarrow f'''(\eta)=\frac{3f''(\eta)}{1-\eta}$$

Comment: How can we find the construction of $h(x)$(in a natural way)? Is it by accident?

Comment: @FFjet  to get something similar astated out with $$\int \frac{f''(x)}{f''(x)}=\int \frac{3}{1-x}$$ which gave me an idea of what it might look like

Comment: Isn't $\frac{f''(x)}{f''(x)}$ equal to $1$?

Comment: @FFjet meant $\frac{f'''(x)}{f''(x)}$